# Using XPath in PHP to get cells from specific table

Tags: php, xpath

I want to extract all the cells of a specific table on a website. The trouble is that the website has three tables which has no id's but all share the same class names. I can get the three tables and all the cells from each, but i only want the second table. How can i do that with XPath? I have the following code:

$search->domxpathquery = "//table[contains(@class,'price-development-table')]/tbody/tr/td";

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($search->url));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$needles = $xpath->query("//table[contains(@class,'price-development-table')]/tbody/tr/td");
```

When instead using only `//table[contains(@class,'price-development-table')]` i can see that there are three tables.

Can i somehow only select cells from the second of those? I've tried using the below:

```
//table[contains(@class,'price-development-table') and position()=2]/tbody/tr/td
//table[contains(@class,'price-development-table')][2]/tbody/tr/td
```

.. but these tries doesnt change anything and still includes all three tables for some reason.

EDIT: 
Added url I'm trying this on:
https://www.q8.dk/priser/prislister/

Comment: URL has been added now :)

Comment: Your XPath needs to be something like `(//table[contains(@class,'price-development-table')])[2]/tbody/tr/td` - so there are brackets round the bit before the `[2]`.

Comment: Arh yes it was indeed the solution. I thought i had already tried just that, but have not made brackets around the `//table[contains(@class,'price-development-table')]` bit